# How can I check if a sequence is alternating?

Tags: java, array

I need to write a program that reads a sequence of integers and determines if the sequence is alternating. An alternating sequence is a sequence of numbers in which every number should be greater or smaller than the one before it according to the base alternation. For example, 1 5 4 8 2 10 is alternating.

I wrote this program but I am not sure it is 100% correct.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class alternating {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int cases = scan.nextInt();
for (int testcase = 0; testcase < cases; testcase++) {
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[] sequence = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++)
        sequence[i] = scan.nextInt();
    if (alternating(sequence))
        System.out.println("alternating");
    else
        System.out.println("not alternating");
}

  }

  public static boolean alternating(int[] sequence) {
   for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 2; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i + 1]) {
        if (sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i + 2])
            return false;
    } else {
        if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1])
            if (sequence[i + 1] >= sequence[i + 2])
                return false;

    }

}
return true;
     }

      }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could properly *indent* your code to make it better legible.

Comment: It must be confirmed to work before we can review it.  Make sure it's tested first.

Comment: It is unclear (to me) whether your definition of "alternating" allows two subsequent numbers to be *equal*. Your code would return true for 2 2 1 and false for 2 2 3.

Comment: For a question to be on-topic for Code Review, the code must be correct to the best of your knowledge. From my reading of the code, it's plausible that you believe that it works. Not being 100% certain is OK.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct for short sequences with less than 3 items.
The method incorrectly returns `true` for these example sequences:

- empty sequence
- singleton list (one item)
- sequence with two items that are equal

For the first 2 cases you might even want to throw `IllegalArgumentException` as arguably it doesn't make much sense to test for alternation in lists with 0 or 1 item, but I think returning `false` is reasonable.

You can do this by adding these conditions at the start of the method:

```
    if (sequence.length < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (sequence.length == 2) {
        return sequence[0] != sequence[1];
    }
```

But actually I would simplify the body of the `for` loop like this:

```
    if (sequence.length < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    int prevCompare = Integer.compare(sequence[0], sequence[1]);
    if (prevCompare == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < sequence.length - 1; ++i) {
        int compare = Integer.compare(sequence[i], sequence[i + 1]);
        if (prevCompare != -compare) {
            return false;
        }
        prevCompare = compare;
    }
    return true;
```

To verify the implementation I recommend adding some unit tests, for example:

```
@Test
public void testEmptyList_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[0]));
}

@Test
public void testSingletonList_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{1}));
}

@Test
public void test2Items_Increasing_Is_Alternating() {
    assertTrue(alternating(new int[]{1, 2}));
}

@Test
public void test2Items_Decreasing_Is_Alternating() {
    assertTrue(alternating(new int[]{3, 2}));
}

@Test
public void test2Items_Same_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{3, 3}));
}

@Test
public void test3Items_Same_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{3, 3, 3}));
}

@Test
public void test4Items_Same_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{3, 3, 3, 3}));
}

@Test
public void test3Items_Increasing_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{3, 4, 5}));
}

@Test
public void test4Items_Increasing_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6}));
}

@Test
public void test3Items_Decreasing_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{43, 34, 25}));
}

@Test
public void test4Items_Decreasing_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{43, 34, 25, 16}));
}

@Test
public void test4Items_AlternatingThenMonotonic_Is_NotAlternating() {
    assertFalse(alternating(new int[]{43, 34, 35, 16, 16, 16}));
}

@Test
public void test4Items_Alternating_Is_Alternating() {
    assertTrue(alternating(new int[]{43, 34, 35, 16}));
}
```